# How do I echo ASCII art that contains special characters in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, symbols, ascii-art

So.. This is (to me anyway) the most important feature of this program. I need this to work. Please don't laugh.. (okay you can laugh) but when my program errors, I want it to display this:

```
          _ _,---._ 
       ,-','       `-.___ 
      /-;'               `._ 
     /\/          ._   _,'o \ 
    ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. ) 
     |\      ,'o     \'    //\ 
     |      \        /   ,--'""`-. 
     :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._ 
      \        `--'  /                ) 
       `.  \`._    ,'     ________,',' 
         .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;' 
          \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,' 
           \( ;  | | )      (`-/ 
             `--'| |)       |-/ 
               | | |        | | 
               | | |,.,-.   | |_ 
               | `./ /   )---`  ) 
              _|  /    ,',   ,-' 
             ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--, 
             |    `--'---.     \/ \ 
             |          / \    /\  \ 
           ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \ 
        ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`. 
       /            \              \   \
```

Echoing each line doesn't work...

```
echo              _ _,---._ 
echo           ,-','       `-.___ 
echo          /-;'               `._ 
echo         /\/          ._   _,'o \ 
echo        ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. ) 
echo         |\      ,'o     \'    //\ 
echo         |      \        /   ,--'""`-. 
echo         :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._ 
echo          \        `--'  /                ) 
echo           `.  \`._    ,'     ________,',' 
echo             .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;' 
echo              \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,' 
echo               \( ;  | | )      (`-/ 
echo                 `--'| |)       |-/ 
echo                   | | |        | | 
echo                   | | |,.,-.   | |_ 
echo                   | `./ /   )---`  ) 
echo                  _|  /    ,',   ,-' 
echo                 ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--, 
echo                 |    `--'---.     \/ \ 
echo                 |          / \    /\  \ 
echo               ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \ 
echo            ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`. 
echo           /            \              \   \
```

I'm assuming this is because of the symbols in the text. Any way to fix it? Or do I need to give up on the "DOH" screen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Store image in a file (doh.txt). Then `type doh.txt` in the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'd really prefer for it to load the ASCII in the cmd prompt though, because it's going to prompt the user for input after the error.

Comment: @user2863294 - Your comment doesn't make sense to me. Your batch script can simply prompt the user for error after it prints the file content to the screen using TYPE.

Comment: OH! I was on a tablet and I didn't realize "type" was part of the command! Brilliant!

Comment: Didn't work for me but `cat doh.txt` did.

Answer (score 27):

Include the following in your script:

```
:::
:::              _ _,---._
:::           ,-','       `-.___
:::          /-;'               `._
:::         /\/          ._   _,'o \
:::        ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. )
:::         |\      ,'o     \'    //\
:::         |      \        /   ,--'""`-.
:::         :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._
:::          \        `--'  /                )
:::           `.  \`._    ,'     ________,','
:::             .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;'
:::              \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,'
:::               \( ;  | | )      (`-/
:::                 `--'| |)       |-/
:::                   | | |        | |
:::                   | | |,.,-.   | |_
:::                   | `./ /   )---`  )
:::                  _|  /    ,',   ,-'
:::                 ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--,
:::                 |    `--'---.     \/ \
:::                 |          / \    /\  \
:::               ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \
:::            ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`.
:::           /            \              \   \
:::

for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%A
```

The image could be placed anywhere within the script. It does not need to be near the FOR statement. I chose `:::` as a distinguishing label for each image line because `:` is used for normal labels, and `::` is frequently used as a comment.

***2014-10-22 Update***

There is an even simpler solution using my [REPL.BAT utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that performs a regex search/replace on stdin and writes the result to stdout. Simply substitute the following line for the FOR statement above:

```
call repl "^:::" "" a <"%~f0"
```

REPL.BAT is pure script that will run on any Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the script. This solution uses the `A` option to only print lines that were altered.

Answer (score 12):

```
cat << "EOF"
          _ _,---._
       ,-','       `-.___
      /-;'               `._
     /\/          ._   _,'o \
    ( /\       _,--'\,','"`. )
     |\      ,'o     \'    //\
     |      \        /   ,--'""`-.
     :       \_    _/ ,-'         `-._
      \        `--'  /                )
       `.  \`._    ,'     ________,','
         .--`     ,'  ,--` __\___,;'
          \`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  /`.,'
           \( ;  | | )      (`-/
             `--'| |)       |-/
               | | |        | |
               | | |,.,-.   | |_
               | `./ /   )---`  )
              _|  /    ,',   ,-'
             ,'|_(    /-<._,' |--,
             |    `--'---.     \/ \
             |          / \    /\  \
           ,-^---._     |  \  /  \  \
        ,-'        \----'   \/    \--`.
       /            \              \   \
EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape special characters (such as `|`, used for pipe redirection) in order for it to work.

However, when using `echo` not all special batch characters need to be escaped, as some as interpreted as text. The ones you still need to escape, and how to escape them, are:

`%` = `%%`

`^` = `^^`

`&` = `^&`

`<` = `^<`

`>` = `^>`

`|` = `^|`

And, if delayed expansion is enabled:

`!` = `^^!`

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
::: Prepare le processeur de commande
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
echo          _ _,---._
echo       ,-','       `-.___
echo      ^/-;'               `._
echo     ^/^\ ^/          ._   _,'o ^\
echo    ( ^/^\       _,--'^\,','"`. )
echo     ^|^\      ,'o     ^\'    ^/ ^/^\
echo     ^|      ^\        ^/   ,--'""`-.
echo     :       ^\_    _ ^/ ,-'         `-._
echo      ^\        `--'  ^/                )
echo       `.  ^\`._    ,'     ________,','
echo         .--`     ,'  ,--` __^\___,;'
echo          ^\`.,-- ,' ,`_)--'  ^/`.,'
echo           ^\( ;  ^| ^| )      (`- ^/
echo             `--'^| ^|)       ^|- ^/
echo               ^| ^| ^|        ^| ^|
echo               ^| ^| ^|,.,-.   ^| ^|_
echo               ^| `. ^/ ^/   )---`  )
echo              _^|  ^/    ,',   ,-'
echo             ,'^|_(    ^/-^<._,' ^|--,
echo             ^|    `--'---.     ^\ ^/ ^\
echo             ^|          ^/ ^\    ^/^\  ^\
echo           ,-^---._     ^|  ^\  ^/  ^\  ^\
echo        ,-'        ^\----'   ^\ ^/    ^\--`.
echo       ^/            ^\              ^\   ^\
PAUSE
EXIT
```

Answer (score -6):

```
echo this one works
echo '                ***     ***
echo                *     * *     *
echo                *    *   *    *
echo                 *** *    ****
echo                   *       *
echo                  *  0   0  *
echo                  *    !    *
echo                  *         *
echo                  *   ~~~   *
echo                  *         *
echo            ======           ======
echo            ======           ======
echo      ======                       ======
echo      ======                       ======
```

Comment: Is this what OP specified?